# unexpected token function when handling facebook response

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

here is my code

```
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
     FB.init({
          appId   : "myappid",
          channelUrl : "//www.mysite/channel.html",
          status  : true, // check login status
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
        });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {

    FB.api(
  "me/bookvote:download",
  "post",
  {
    book: "http://samples.ogp.me/199815506812566",
    fb:explicitly_shared = "true"
  }

 function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
     alert("Error occured" + response.error);
   } else {
    alert("Post ID: " + response.id);
    }
    }
 )





   // else {
   //do nothing since user did not authorize
  // alert("I am an alert box!");

    // }
    }
    }
    )

    </script>';
```

the error i am getting in console is Unexpected token function when I add the

```
 function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
     alert("Error occured" + response.error);
   } else {
    alert("Post ID: " + response.id);
    }
    }
 )
```

this was demonstrated by facebook here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/,
The posts are not being made to the developers faecbook wall so I need to handle the response to see what error messages are being printed by facebook 
is there another way to handle the response?

Comment: It's a Javascript syntax error, nothing to do with facebook as the code doesn't even run.

Comment: what syntax is wrong then? I have all the brackets correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some indentation:

```
FB.init({
    appId: "myappid",
    channelUrl: "//www.mysite/channel.html",
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true // parse XFBML
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        FB.api("me/bookvote:download", "post", {
            book: "http://samples.ogp.me/199815506812566",
            fb: explicitly_shared = "true" //? Is syntactically valid but creates a global
        } //Missing a , here?

        function (response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert("Error occured" + response.error);
            } else {
                alert("Post ID: " + response.id);
            }
        })

    }
})
```